# Meteor ports used (seems to be blocked by wireless network)

Tags: meteor

I have a strange problem in one specific wireless network: Collections are not accessible and are all empty when doing `collection.find().fetch()`. I can add new documents to minimongo (and find them) but I never see documents loaded from mongodb, nor are new documents synced to the server. Remember, this only occurs in one specific wireless network.

This behaviour only occurs when deployed to my own server, not when deployed to meteor.com

The meteor project itself is just one file:

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("players");
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("players", function() {
    return Players.find();
  });
}
```

Packages installed are

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

preserve-inputs
standard-app-packages
insecure
```

Version is 0.6.5

I do the testing directly in the Javascript console.

`Players.insert({name:'test2'})` will create a new document, but this document is not found when doing `Players.find().fetch()` AFTER a reload. On meteor.com, the document is found after a reload.

Address of meteor.com deploy: `http://testcollections.meteor.com/`
Address of my own deploy: `http://146.185.130.93/`

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you add documents to minimongo, are they synchronized to the actual mongodb? Chrome developer tools -> Network can help to get more information (is there a websocket connection and did Meteor switch to sockjs or not)

Comment: No, I do not think they got to the actual mongodb. I will check for a websocket connection in Chrome.

Comment: Is it possible that the wireless network is using proxies? just speculating, but a proxy server may be messing things up, so you might check that after doing your network checks suggested above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds a bit like the websocket bit of the connection isn't connecting through. In meteor there are two connections, one static containing the html, images and js (which looks like its working) and the other via websockets which handles the data & live updates.

You could check in Chrome's javascript error console for a 400 websocket error, in which case it tries to drop to long polling, which takes quite a while.

It might be something like a proxy which is troubling you. I've run into this without a HTTP proxy but a invisible socks proxy too (via iptables).

You could check quickly too by checking `Meteor.status()` which would indicate its 'waiting' if the above is the case.

Comment: If you add back `autopublish` does it work? (with `meteor add autopublish`?) It looks like the subscriptions aren't getting a reply back

Comment: It does not. Also if `autopublish` is added, I have no content in my collections. I tried it in the same network environment with a leaderboard example and there it works, independent of `autopublish` being enabled or not. Therefore it must have to do something with my application. I will try to create a minimal testcase.

Comment: Ok. I have a testcase now. It works as expected when deployed to meteor.com but does not work if deployed to my own server. Remember, the error only occurs in a specific wireless network. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Now I did. The interesting thing is that now I get a `WebSocket connection to 'ws://willmit.com/sockjs/179/3upzoh92/websocket' failed: Unexpected response code: 400` error when I connect to http://146.185.130.93/ from a different wirelesse network. There is no error message when connecting from the specific wireless network. My analysis now would be that, on the network in question, the client never finds out that the websocket connection does not work. Another question now would be: how to enable websocket connections on my own server?

Comment: Is there a way to tell Meteor manually to not use a websocket connection?

Comment: Ok, I ran the app with DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true and it works as expected. Is there any extended explanation available on the advantages and disadvantages of websockets with meteor?

Comment: It would be nice if meteor would disable websockets automatically, even in this special case. Is there a way to turn of websockets client-side at runtime?

Comment: Meteor is supposed to fall back to long polling in the event that it can't establish a ws connection, its just it takes a bit of time, so using `DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS` cuts that out and uses long polling directly

Comment: Websockets/long polling are needed for the live/reactive/any data to work, the difference with long polling and websockets would be pretty much speed. I think meteor used long polling exclusively all the way up from the first version to 0.6 or something so it shouldn't be much of a noticable impact without it. the difference does exist but its very minute

Comment: Ok, so I will disable websockets for now. Would be nice to only disable them if they do not work, though.